# iOS - UIStoryboardSegue detecting table cell and opening a viewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

So I have a UITableView, and the cells are connected to a UIStoryboardSegue in order to open a new UIViewController. After clicking a cell `prepareForSegue` get's called and everything works fine.

**QUESTION:** In the follwoing method how can i know what is the indexPath of the selected cell in my TableView?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ObjectDetailViewController *mvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    // PassingObject *obj = [self.array objectAtIndex: ? ];
    mvc.passingObject = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Assume self.view is the table view
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    DetailObject *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
    [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been switching from nibs to using storyboards, and it's been a challenge because there is not good documentation. Is there a good blog or tutorial for storyboards?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial related to your question: [Raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2). You can check their other tutorials as well.

Comment: the above is probably the only decent tutorial out there.  I even own several IOS5 books that barely scratch the surface of storyboards.  The simpler the UI the more storyboards seems to be beneficial. The most custom, the more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] (look at the DJPlayer answer) you can use [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender], since sender is a selected cell in this case.